# Is Datastream able to write on an already existing table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-datastream

I created a stream job having mysql and bigquery as my source and destination connection profiles respectively, and the job was able to successfully replicate the source tables and data into the bigquery tables(which were created by datastream itself). I wanted to understand can use datastream again to modify the created bigquery table schema to add for example, policy tags to it and somehow add partitioning to those tables?

Answer (score 0):

The schema update in BigQuery is now pretty flexible: you can rename the column, change the type, add and remove column. you can also alter the column mode (nullable, default value,...)

However, you can't partition a non partitioned table. In that case, you must recreate the table.

---

**Update 1**

You can add a new column with a default value, like this

```
ALTER TABLE `<dataset>.<table>` 
ADD COLUMN ingestion_time  TIMESTAMP;

ALTER TABLE `<dataset>.<table>`
ALTER COLUMN ingestion_time  SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

Then, all the subsequent entry will be created with the default value if the field is not explicitly mentioned and populated.

Comment: This makes sense. Just to add to my question is there any way we can get an ingestion_time data that we can get through datastream, because I saw the documentation we have a metadata field datastream.source_timestamp but this is completely different maybe some way for ingestion_time to keep track when did the datatsream replicated the records.

Comment: Got it, I proposed something in the update of my answer.